# SetResolution does nothing when joining tiff images

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, resolution, tiff

I've been trying to adjust the resolution for a new tiff that gets created from a group of other tiffs. I would like to drop the resolution to 100x100 dpi. Everything with the join works properly but the resolution in the final tiff will always be what the resolution is of the files I am joining together (used 300x300 dpi images). I have tried using some suggestions ([Set DPI value to Tiff Image in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084725/set-dpi-value-to-tiff-image-in-c-sharp)) for getting/setting the PropertyItems but that has failed as well. Using the join technique below, what would be the proper way to set the resolution of the final image to 100x100 dpi?

Thank you.

```
public byte[] JoinTiffImages(
        List<byte[]> images)
    {
        var fPage = FrameDimension.Page;

        var nearest =
            System.Drawing
                  .Drawing2D
                  .InterpolationMode
                  .NearestNeighbor;

        if (images.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new ImageConverterException(
                "Could not join an empty set of images.");
        }
        else if (images.Count == 1)
        {
            return images[0];
        }
        else
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var masterBitmap =
                    (Bitmap)DrawingImage.FromStream(
                        new MemoryStream(images[0])))
                {
                    //get the codec for tiff files
                    var info = GetTifCodecInfo();
                    var enc = Encoder.SaveFlag;
                    var ep = new EncoderParameters(2);

                    ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(
                        enc,
                        (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);

                    ep.Param[1] = new EncoderParameter(
                        Encoder.Compression,
                        (long)TifCompression.ToEncoderValue());

                    masterBitmap.SetResolution(100.0f, 100.0f);
                    masterBitmap.Save(ms, info, ep);

                    //save the intermediate frames
                    ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(
                        enc,
                        (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);

                    for (int i = 1; i < images.Count; i++)
                    {
                        using (var nextImg = (Bitmap)DrawingImage.FromStream(
                            new MemoryStream(images[i])))
                        {
                            for (int x = 0;
                                    x < nextImg.GetFrameCount(fPage);
                                    x++)
                            {
                                nextImg.SetResolution(100.0f, 100.0f);
                                nextImg.SelectActiveFrame(fPage, x);

                                masterBitmap.SaveAdd(nextImg, ep);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    ep.Param[0] =
                        new EncoderParameter(
                            enc,
                            (long)EncoderValue.Flush);

                    //close out the file.
                    masterBitmap.SaveAdd(ep);

                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This may/may not be related to your issue, but you are doing a lot of work that you are throwing away when you create a new Bitmap called `img`, get a Graphics object from it, paint `nextImg` into it, and then just dump it.  I am wondering if you intended to add `img` to the `masterBitmap`.  Along with that, have you tried setting the resolution of `img` and adding that to the master as opposed to adding `nextImg` to the master.

Comment: You need to set the resolution __before__ you draw the image, for both the drawn and the receiving  image! You do it right for nextImg but wrong for masterBitmap.

Comment: Pretty unclear what you *expected* to happen.  Not much should be expected, SetResolution() merely sets a reference number.  There are glaring bugs in the code, SaveAdd(nextImg, ep) surely should use *img* instead.  And SetResolution() was never called for *img*.  And the DrawImage() overload that takes a Rectangle should be used.

Comment: Just wondering why someone would downvote this question.  It seems it is laid out and provides a complete code example.  Heck, the guy even said Thank you.

Comment: @TaW Please explain? I call SetResolution on the masterBitmap before the initial call to save the same way I do for any subsequent SaveAdd calls for the rest of the images.

Comment: I think I got your post wrong. sorry. Or did you change the question?  I thought I saw an DrawImageUnscaled before..? - Anyway, I add an answer, tested to work, that creates a multipage tif with the dpi chosen.

Comment: @TaW DrawImageUnscaled is there in the edit history in the original post.

Comment: Thanks Lars, I thought so..

Comment: @TaW Yes it was originally there. I modified the code based on the comments above but it was moving in the wrong direction. Thank you. Your answer does work for changing the resolution but has the side affect of change the size. I needed to be able to just change the resolution without change the overall image size so the image.

Comment: How does the (current) solution change the size? Note: The first version made use of an ImageList, which can hold only images of one size.

Comment: Just changing the resolution changes the print size of an image. Take an image 1000x1000 pixels at 100x100 dpi. It will print 10"x10". Make it 50x50 dpi and it will print 20"x20". The solution needs to change the resolution but keep the print size the same. As far as your image list comment, not sure how that has anything to do with this implementation. An image can be any size. In any case, thank you again for your comments/solution, it works for a specific scenario, just not mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue with some help from the comments. This function will handle the resolution change without the image changing size.

```
public static byte[] JoinTiffImages(
    List<byte[]> images,
    float res)
{
    var fPage = FrameDimension.Page;

    var nearest =
        System.Drawing
                .Drawing2D
                .InterpolationMode
                .NearestNeighbor;

    if (images.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception(
            "Could not join an empty set of images.");
    }
    else if (images.Count == 1)
    {
        return images[0];
    }
    else
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();

        //get the codec for tiff files
        var info = GetTifCodecInfo();
        var ep = new EncoderParameters(2);

        ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(
            System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag,
            (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);

        ep.Param[1] = new EncoderParameter(
            System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression,
            (long)EncoderValue.CompressionLZW);

        using (var masterImg =
            (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(
                new MemoryStream(images[0])))
        {
            using (var resizedMaster =
                new Bitmap(
                    (int)(masterImg.Width *
                        (res /
                            masterImg.HorizontalResolution)),
                    (int)(masterImg.Height *
                        (res /
                            masterImg.VerticalResolution))))
            {
                resizedMaster.SetResolution(
                    res,
                    res);

                using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(resizedMaster))
                {
                    gr.InterpolationMode = nearest;

                    gr.DrawImage(
                        masterImg,
                        new Rectangle(
                            0,
                            0,
                            resizedMaster.Width,
                            resizedMaster.Height),
                        0,
                        0,
                        masterImg.Width,
                        masterImg.Height,
                        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }

                resizedMaster.Save(ms, info, ep);

                //save the intermediate frames
                ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag,
                    (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);

                for (int i = 1; i < images.Count; i++)
                {
                    using (var nextImg =
                        (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(
                        new MemoryStream(images[i])))
                    {
                        for (int x = 0;
                            x < nextImg.GetFrameCount(fPage);
                            x++)
                        {
                            nextImg.SelectActiveFrame(fPage, x);

                            using (var resizedNext =
                                new Bitmap(
                                    (int)(nextImg.Width *
                                        (res /
                                            nextImg.HorizontalResolution)),
                                    (int)(nextImg.Height *
                                        (res /
                                            nextImg.VerticalResolution))))
                            {
                                resizedNext.SetResolution(
                                    res,
                                    res);

                                using (var gr =
                                    Graphics.FromImage(resizedNext))
                                {
                                    gr.InterpolationMode = nearest;
                                    gr.DrawImage(
                                        nextImg,
                                        new Rectangle(
                                            0,
                                            0,
                                            resizedNext.Width,
                                            resizedNext.Height),
                                        0,
                                        0,
                                        nextImg.Width,
                                        nextImg.Height,
                                        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                                }

                                resizedMaster.SaveAdd(resizedNext, ep);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                ep.Param[0] =
                    new EncoderParameter(
                        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag,
                        (long)EncoderValue.Flush);

                //close out the file.
                resizedMaster.SaveAdd(ep);
            }

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}

private static ImageCodecInfo GetTifCodecInfo()
{
    foreach (var ice in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
    {
        if (ice.MimeType == "image/tiff")
        {
            return ice;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I notice you also added support for adjusting each frame of the source images.  Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that creates a multi-page tif file from a list of images.
It sets the DPI both to the master and all parts according to an input paramter.

```
private void saveTiff_Click(List<Image> imgList, string saveName,  int dpi)
{
    //all kudos to : http://bobpowell.net/generating_multipage_tiffs.aspx

    foreach (Image img in imgList) ((Bitmap)img).SetResolution(dpi, dpi);

    System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder enc = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag;
    Bitmap master = new Bitmap(imgList[0]);
    master.SetResolution(dpi, dpi);
    ImageCodecInfo info = null;

    // lets hope we have an TIF encoder
    foreach (ImageCodecInfo ice in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
        if (ice.MimeType == "image/tiff")  info = ice;

    // one parameter: MultiFrame
    EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters(1);
    ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);
    master.Save(saveName, info, ep);

    // one parameter: further frames
    ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
    for (int i = 1; i < imgList.Count; i++)  master.SaveAdd(imgList[i], ep);

    // one parameter: flush
    ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
    master.SaveAdd(ep);
}
```